# Shorter method to derive the same result?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, convergence-divergence, euler-mascheroni-constant

### Background

I was recently fiddling with some math and realized I could come with the below formula. However, I am unsatisfied with my proof as it is not too lengthy and I am not sure about some steps (but I am confident in the result).

$$\gamma  = \lim_{n \to \infty}(\sum_{r=1}^{n^2}  \frac{1}{(n+r)a_{n,r}} - \ln n)$$

Where $\gamma$ is Euler's constant and $a_{n,r}= ((r−1) \mod n)+1$

### Question

Can anyone else provide a shorter (another) proof for the same result? Does this converge to the the constant quicker than the original series (below)?

$$ \gamma = \lim_{n \to \infty} (1+ 1/2 + 1/3 + \dots 1/n - \ln n)$$

Comment: your definition of $a_n$ does not make sense.

Comment: @GabrielRomon It's basically $a_n= \text{remainder of n when dividing } r$

Comment: However, at $r=n$,$r=2n$,etc we choose the remainder to be $n$ instead of $0$

Comment: $r$ is a fixed number that you define once and for all ?

Comment: $r$ is the index of the sum.

Comment: My second comment should read $a_r$ instead of $a_n$

Comment: Reason for downvote?

Comment: FWIW, one can write $$a_r = ((r-1)\bmod n) +1$$
(but writing $a_{n,r}$ would make more sense, as it also depends on $n$)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aside from $r=1,n+1,2n+1,3n+1,\cdots ,n(n-1)+1$ which all result $a_{n,r} =1$ the other $r$'s $1 \leq r \leq n^2$ give the result that $a_{n,r} \geq 2$.

So we want to maximize $\sum \limits_{r=1}^{n^2} \frac{1}{(n+r)a_{n,r}} $ so we know that $\sum \limits_{r=1}^{n^2} \frac{1}{(n+r)a_{n,r}} \leq \sum \limits_{r=1}^{n^2} \frac{1}{2(n+r)} + \sum \limits_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{1}{2(n+n k+1)} = \frac{n H_{n^2+n}-H_{\frac{1}{n}}-n H_n+H_{n+\frac{1}{n}}}{2 n}$

With the fact that $ H_n \leq \ln n +1$.

We get that $\frac{n H_{n^2+n}-H_{\frac{1}{n}}-n H_n+H_{n+\frac{1}{n}}}{2 n} \leq \frac{1}{n}+\frac{\log (n)}{2 n}-\frac{\log (n)}{2}+\frac{1}{2} \log (n
   (n+1))+\frac{\log \left(n+\frac{1}{n}\right)}{2 n}+1 \leq \frac{2 \log (n)}{3}$.

So $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} (\sum \limits_{r=1}^{n^2} \frac{1}{(n+r)a_{n,r}}-\ln n)= - \infty$

**Edit** : As for the second question $\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}+\cdots +\frac{1}{n}= H_n = \ln n + \gamma +\frac{1}{2 n} +O(n^{-2})$, so a better convergences is $\gamma = \lim \limits_{n \to \infty} (\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n} - \ln n -\frac{1}{2n})$

Comment: $\log$ and $\ln$ here both denote the natural logarithm.